# How to use NServiceBus.FLRetries header (NSB 5.2)

Tags: nservicebus

I have a PowerShell script that replays the MSMQ messages from an error queue. I was hoping that **NServiceBus.FLRetries** updates with further failures. However this is not the case.

I have read the [documentation](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/headers?version=core_5) but unable to fully understand this particular header.

What I would like to see is the number of retries increase as the message continue to fail to process (e.g. web service not available).

I am using NSB 5.2.

Any ideas how I can model this if the above header is not usable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this won't work.

NServiceBus implements **First level retries(FLR)** by rolling the receive transaction against the queue back if there is an exception. Rolling the transaction back means the message *"never left"* the queue in the first place. You can't thus modify the message, including adding/updating any headers like **NServiceBus.FLRetries**. NServiceBus keeps track of this count in-memory instead.

If the message keeps failing and is moved to **Second Level Retries(SLR)**, NServiceBus will add the **NServiceBus.FLRetries** header to show how many **FLR** retries were attempted in total.

If you really need to keep track of the number of retries you can disable **FLR** and use only **SLR** instead. **SLR** retries increment the **NServiceBus.Retries** header for each retry since they don't rely on rolling the receive transaction back.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this make sense. Toying around SLRs at the moment.